# Trying to build prediction model

Tags: time-series, multiple-regression, model

I have pollution data for a month (daily each hour) with this data and data from satellite I have build regression models for few days. 
My question is...

> **Is it possible to build model that will predict pollution for next day?**
>    Based on daily concentration, temperature, wind speed/direction, humidity, type of area (industrial...) and correlation between NDVI

This can be not quite direct question, but I have only start learning. Thanks for answers!

Comment: Can you explain your dataset further?

Comment: @Dawny33 question edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Is it possible to build model that will predict pollution for next day?**

Yes, it is possible to build a model to predict pollution for the next day. It is called time-series modelling.

These [texts](https://www.otexts.org/fpp) by Rob Hyndman and George are a nice way to learn and understand the intuition of time series forecasting, with some nice hands-on examples.

As you already mentioned that you used regression, I'm not including the variants of it like multiple-regression,etc. And your question seems like a self-study question, so I have included the above text for developing a nice intuition about building forecasting models using time-series.

Comment: yes it is self-learning, thanks for text I will look at them.